# Land usage radius from different layer

Tags: qgis, layers, surface

I am very new to using QGIS but what I am trying to do is:

1. Load a WFS of 'land usages' in the netherlands (PDOK)
2. plot store locations over the land usages
3. take a 750 meter radius around the store
4. see for every store the amount of different landusage within the radius. For instance of the roughly 1.7 square KM -> 300m2 is "highways" and 100m2 is "business park"
5. Export this to a CSV

What i have reached so far is my step 1, 2 and 3:
[image: Ground usage with store + radius]

I have figured out how i can get the shapes of land usage within the circle and touching it, however i want to know exactly the amount of space for every type of land usage in my circle (and then for every store).

Comment: `intersect` is the magical word you're searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use intersect, or clip to create a new layer. In the attribute table of the new layer go to field calculator, create a new (decimal field) and calculate the area by using $area as the expression.